# NodeJS process 'uncaughtException' not working in some circumstances

Tags: node.js, events, asynchronous, error-handling, process

I have a nodeJS project works fine in my local when using

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('*********some  code*************');
});
```

This snippet of code gets called when any sync or any async Error happens.

But when I put my project to two the other Linux hosts:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS,
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

One works fine, but the other never gets called when Error happens and project shutdown directly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I would refer you to the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_warning_using_uncaughtexception_correctly) about using the `uncaughtException` event correctly.

The most important part is: "**It is not safe to resume normal operation after 'uncaughtException'.**" The code sample you have here shows that you are logging something, but not exiting the process.

It is possible that on your other system that the process is dying due to the exception, perhaps because of a native module that is having a segmentation fault or other process-ending crash.

Consider catching your exceptions at the points where they occur, and using  `uncaughtException` as an event of last resort for logging fatal errors, while handing off to `process.exit(1)` to end the process with an error code.

Comment: Thanks!  But, if an `uncaughtException` can't get called, I can't do any graceful shutdown process, it just shutdown directly without logging or noticing.